# Online PDF reader for my own site other than Scribd?

Tags: flash, pdf, scribd

I am using Scribd API (www.scribd.com) to display the PDF files in my website. I just want to know is there any other PDF API which i can use to embed the PDF in my website. FASTER and MORE customizable than Scribd, Mainly i want to put my company logo in that API, whereas in scribd they are displaying there logo.

So just want to know any opensource, FREE and customizable PDF API for website.

Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Depending on how much functionality you're looking for, it's not incredibly difficult to roll your own. [SWFTools](http://www.swftools.org/) lets you convert PDF to SWF, a format you can load in to a simple Flash viewer.

Answer (score 4):

Sure, you can use Google Docs Viewer (you don't need to have a google docs account): https://docs.google.com/viewer - Instructions are on the page

Answer (score 2):

You can also try http://issuu.com. But it's not SEO friendly.

Answer (score 1):

May be you could try this one: [FreepapeR](http://lededansdubocal.net/spip.php?article22)